# Issue with Buld Pipeline in DevOps with Self Hosted Agent

Tags: azure, build, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, agent

My Team and I have researched this at great lenght and we cannot figure out why our Build in Azure DevOps Pipeline does not download any source code to the self hosted Agent running the build.

We have a project called "ProjWindowsService", a normal .NET Windows Service project using Topshelf.

We have the source code checked into the Repo in DevOps, the project is mapped in the Build Pipline but once agent runs the build job it cant find the source files and gives the error:

```
MSBUILD: MSBUILD : error MSB1009: Project file does not exist.
Switch: c:\it\agent\4\s\XXXXXX.API.Integration.Domain\XXXXX.API.Integration.Domain.sln
```

Basically there is nothing under the c:\it\agent\4\s on the agent (our understanding is that the source files should be copied to this location) except for the $tf which in itself has no files.

So the error message makes perfect sense, but we have selected and tried in multiple ways to configure the Source part of the Build Pipline without any success.

[Build Pipline Source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/roxhQ.png)
Would really appreciate some help in figuring out why the source code is not being downloaded to agent working folder.

Get Source Log:

```
##[command]tf vc workspace /delete ws_4_15%3Bccb20099-639d-42db-a116-f6f52fecd57d /collection:https://XXXXXX.visualstudio.com/ /loginType:OAuth /login:.,*** /noprompt

##[command]tf vc workspace /new /location:local /permission:Public ws_4_15 /collection:https://XXXXX.visualstudio.com/ /loginType:OAuth /login:.,*** /noprompt

##[command]tf vc workfold /unmap /workspace:ws_4_15 $/ /collection:https://XXXXX.visualstudio.com/ /loginType:OAuth /login:.,*** /noprompt

##[command]tf vc workfold /map /workspace:ws_4_15 "$/XXXXX Software Test" C:\IT\WorkFolder\4\s\$(Agent.BuildDirectory) /collection:https://XXXXX.visualstudio.com/ /loginType:OAuth /login:.,*** /noprompt

##[command]tf vc get /version:2 /recursive /overwrite C:\IT\WorkFolder\4\s /loginType:OAuth /login:.,*** /noprompt
##[debug]Starting process:
##[debug]  File name: 'tf'
##[debug]  Arguments: 'vc get /version:2 /recursive /overwrite C:\IT\WorkFolder\4\s /loginType:OAuth /login:.,*** /noprompt'
##[debug]  Working directory: 'C:\IT\WorkFolder\4\s'
##[debug]  Require exit code zero: 'True'
##[debug]  Encoding web name: windows-1252 ; code page: '1252'
##[debug]  Force kill process on cancellation: 'False'
##[debug]  Redirected STDIN: 'False'
##[debug]  Persist current code page: 'False'
##[debug]  Keep redirected STDIN open: 'False'
##[debug]  High priority process: 'False'
##[debug]OOM score adjustment is Linux-only.
##[debug]Process started with process id 20656, waiting for process exit.
All files are up to date.
##[debug]STDOUT/STDERR stream read finished.
##[debug]STDOUT/STDERR stream read finished.
##[debug]Finished process 20656 with exit code 0, and elapsed time 00:00:01.9414527.
```

Comment: Take a look at that part of the build log where it tries to sync sources. If there's anything wrong there, it must output some sort of an error or warning. It sounds like a permission problem...

Comment: Added get source log part to post

Comment: I think you are correct it is a permission issue but cant figure out where, as mentioned below using GitHub source it works fine but not using VSTC.